# How to store textbox data with attached function in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to store one more textbox data with attached function in Laravel 5.7.

I have three tables products, raws and product_raw. in **Product_raw** table I stored product_id and raw_id.

**Controller.php**

```
$post->products()->attach($request->product);
$post->raws()->attach($request->raws);
```

**View.php**

```
 @foreach($raws as $value) 
 <div class="form-group">            
         <input type="text" name="quantity"><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="raws" value="raws[]"><br>

  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: just the way you have stored in `product_raw` table. you can save in `other tables` in same manner. so what is the problem?

Comment: In the view the variable name is `raw`. In controller you are using `$request->raws` plural. Could that be it? 
If not. please give some more info.